# Passing std::vector<bool> to an external function

Tags: c++, boolean, stdvector, hpc

I am dealing with a library of which I cannot change the data types. I need to call a function that takes a `bool` array. The code that I am working with uses `std::vector<bool>` to store the bools. I have read a lot about `std::vector<bool>` and the associated problems on SO, but I have not found the most elegant solution for my problem. This is a code where performance is crucial. How do I deal with this problem in the most efficient way? I can change the type stored in the `std::vector`, but I cannot escape from using `std::vector`.

In my own problem, I have to call Fortran functions, but I have made a minimal example in C++ that illustrates the problem.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>

void print_c_bool(bool* bool_array, size_t n)
{
    for (int i=0; i<n; ++i)
        printf("%d, %d\n", i, bool_array[i]);
}

int main()
{
    // This works.
    bool bool_array[5] = {true, false, false, true, false};
    print_c_bool(bool_array, 5);

    // This is impossible, but how to solve it?
    std::vector<bool> bool_vector {true, false, false, true, false};
    // print_c_bool(bool_vector.data(), bool_vector.size());

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::vector<char>` can be used to hold `0`s or `1`s, though i'd also love to see a better workaround

Comment: You have to construct an array of bools, that's the only way.

Comment: What about this: `std::vector<char> bool_vector{ 1, 0 }; print_c_bool((bool *)bool_vector.data(), bool_vector.size());`? Roughly.

Comment: @vahancho No. It violates strict alias rule and will not work when `sizeof(char) != sizeof(bool)` and in other cases.

Comment: I am afraid you'll have to accept the fact that `std::vector<bool>::data` is not an array of booleans, if you need one then you have to use something else than `std::vector<bool>`

Comment: @KamilCuk you are right. `sizeof(bool)` may not be equal to 1. I have deleted my answer as I assumed that `sizeof(bool)` is always 1.

Comment: If braking strict alias violation I would go with `class Bool { bool v; };` with at least `static_assert(sizeof(Bool) == sizeof(bool) && std::is_pod<Bool> == true)` and then call `reinterpret_cast<bool*>(std::vector<Bool>::data())`. Looks as dirty as other casting solutions and seems to work on my system.

Comment: `<rant>`It is really a pity that the standard has defined `std::vector<bool>` not to be a vector of `bool`!`</rant>` But it is a fact... My opinion is that you should define a custom container that behaves as a `vector` for the functions that your really need. Even with no special optimization, it could not be worse than repeatedly converting from a bitset (what a `std::vector<bool` is) and a `bool` array. It would not be a true `std::vector`, but could be used (almost) as if it was...

Comment: if you have a std::vector<bool> why don't you pass that to the print function? if you need the print function also for bool*, you could still make it a template...

Comment: @choosyg. I cannot do that, because I cannot modify those functions, because it is an external library.

Answer (score 5):

You know what you have to do... Create a temporary array of bools and copy the values.

```
auto v = new bool[bool_vector.size()];
std::copy(bool_vector.begin(), bool_vector.end(), v);
print_c_bool(v, bool_vector.size());
delete[] v;
```

or

```
auto v = std::make_unique<bool>(bool_vector.size());
std::copy(bool_vector.begin(), bool_vector.end(), v.get());
print_c_bool(v.get(), bool_vector.size());
```

Comment: I would like to avoid the copies, as this is a big performance killer.

Answer (score 2):

> I can change the type stored in the `std::vector`, but I cannot escape
>   from using `std::vector`.

In this case you are out of luck. `std::vector<bool>` does not store an array of booleans, neither does its `data()` return a pointer to an array of booleans (as all other `std::vectors` do for their respective data type).

You can play some tricks and use `std::vector<uint8_t>` or similar, though even if the size matches, a `uint8_t*` is not a `bool*` ! Given that the function cannot change, you can only avoid to violate strict aliasing by copying the data into a bool array.

If you do care about performance, then I'd suggest to consider not using `std::vector<bool>`. For example, do you really need dynamic size? If not use a `std::array`.

Comment: I need a dynamic size, unfortunately. The `uint8_t` seems to work nicely, but is guaranteed to work everywhere?

Comment: @Chiel it is never guaranteed to work! You missed the "a `uint8_t*` is not a `bool*`!" Passing a `uint8_t*` when a `bool*` is expected may appear to work, but afaik it violates [strict aliasing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule). The strict aliasing rule is a tricky one, because something that naively seems to be fine in fact is not, and a tiny compiler optimization can completely screw your program

Answer (score 0):

I tried to make it work using your example and the following (quite dirty) solution worked fine:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void test_print(bool * arr, size_t s)
{
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i< s; ++i)
        std::cout << i << ": " << (arr[i]?"true\n":"false\n");
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    bool b_arr[5] = {true, false, false, true, false};
    test_print(b_arr, 5);

    //std::vector <uint8_t> b_vec = {true, false, false, true, false}; // former proposal
    std::vector <char> b_vec = {true, false, false, true, false}; // new proposal
    test_print(reinterpret_cast<bool*>(b_vec.data()), b_vec.size());

    return 0;
}
```

The output I got is:

> 0: true
>   1: false
>   2: false
>   3: true
>   4: false
>   0: true
>   1: false
>   2: false
>   3: true
>   4: false

However, I don't know if it will behave the same on every system/platform. But if you don't intend to change your system/platform and if it does work on yours, I think it could do the job even if it is a quite dirty solution.

In fact, if we can guarantee that `sizeof(bool) == sizeof(uint8_t)` and assuming that `true` and `false` are respectively treated in memory as integers `1` and `0`, this solution will work, but not otherwise.

I hope it can help.

EDIT: Replaced `uint8_t` by `char` type.

---

EDIT2:

Another solution that does not violate the strict aliasing rule is the one that ***Kamil Cuk*** mentioned that is to create a Bool wrapper and still check that `sizeof(bool) == sizeof(Bool)`.

A possible implementation (just the baseline code) can be:

```
struct Bool
{
    bool v;

    Bool(bool bv=false) : v(bv)
    {}
};
```

And then you will be able to write:

```
std::vector<Bool> b_vec {true, false, false, true, false};
test_print(reinterpret_cast<bool*>(b_vec.data()), b_vec.size());
```

It worked for me :)

Comment: Interesting. Then the big open question is to which extent we can guarantee this. Any ideas on that?

Comment: `uint8_t` (if defined of course) will always have the same size by definition. According to me, this question is more about the size of `bool`. But I don't really know in which cases it is 1 (8 bits) and in which cases it is not (it depends on the platform I think).

Comment: afaik `bool` and `uint8_t` are not compatible with respect to [strict aliasing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule) and what appears to work is not guaranteed to work.

Comment: @user463035818 If we use `char` instead of `uint8_t`, we are not violated the strict aliasing rule anymore, and the size of `char` is guaranteed to be 1. The result is the same. Thanks for noticing my error, I didn't know that.

Comment: afaik the exception is for a `char*` aliasing a pointer of different type. It is not for any other type aliasing a `char*`. And it is the latter you use in your code.

Comment: you can find the relevant quotes from the standard [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7005988/4117728). In a nutshell: you can access a bool via a char pointer but you shall not access a char via a `bool*`

Comment: Oh you are right, my bad. @Chiel Without any compiler optimization enabled and if the platform does respect what I specified in my answer, it will work fine. This is the only way I see to avoid the copy. Hope it helps.

Comment: I edited my answer, this is the idea that @Kamil Cuk proposed (not mine) and seems to work properly.